# Print a JSON data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON.

```
{
    "lang": [
        {
            "SECTION_NAME": {
                "english": "My title"
            },
            "SECTION_NAME_2": {
                "english": "My title"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm looking to print the value like this:

```
$.getJSON('json/lang.json', function(data) {
    var text = data['lang']['SECTION_NAME'];
    $('#title').html(text.english);
});
```

But I have the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'text.english')
```

Any help please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access it via index as `lang` is an array of object

like this

```
console.log(data['lang'][0]['SECTION_NAME'])
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/08tfvjte/)

Comment: How can I change my array to make something like `data['lang']['SECTION_NAME'].english` ? Because, if my son change, I need to change all the `[x]`...

Comment: then object design should be `{ lang : { section : { english : 'My title' } }` @roberto

Comment: oh my bad :(  , `{ lang : { SECTION_NAME  : { english : 'My title' } }` . now try :) @roberto

Answer (score 1):

The value of `lang` is an **array** which contains an object.

You are ignoring the array and trying to access the objects as if it was the value of `lang` directly.